# Script executing fine, but not writing to any files in specified directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-writing, listiterator

I am trying to write a script that will iterate through a specified directory, and write to any .txt files with a new string.

**Edited after reading Lev Levitsky's explanation**

```
import os

x = raw_input("Enter the directory path here: ")

def rootdir(x):
    for dirpaths, dirnames, files in os.walk(x):
        for filename in files:
            try:
                with open(os.paths.join(dirpaths, filename 'a')) as f:
                    f.write("newline")
            except:
                print "Directory empty or unable to open file"
            return x
rootdir(x)
```

The script executes, however I get my "Directory empty or unable to open file" exception.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: what is `os.dirpaths.join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the whole script, then your function is never called, so no wonder nothing happens to the files. You need to actually call the function with the user-provided path:

```
rootdir(x)
```

Other issues I see with your code:

- The function will erase the text file's content and replace it with "newline". That is because you open the file in write mode. Consider using append mode (`'a'`) instead.
- There is no `os.dirpaths`. You need `os.path.join(dirpaths, filename)`. Also, `'w'` is an argument to `join`, but it should be an argument to `open`. So in fact the files will be opened in read mode and with incorrect names, resulting in an error.
- Finally, because of the `return` statement inside the loop body, the function will return after processing just one file, without touching the rest.

Comment: Ah! Of course regarding calling the function. I changed to enter the raw_input and forgot to re-enter the call. 

I also already made the append change after doing some documentation reading.

I read what you explained regarding joining the dirpaths and filename to give .open something legible to read and open, and was able to edit my code accordingly. **The thing I am not sure about now however, is the appropriate syntax to input the 'a' argument for the .open function.

Comment: It's just the second argument to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open): `open(os.path.join(...), 'a')`.

Comment: Executing just fine however still throwing my exception. Something is wrong with my logic apparently. 

`with open(os.paths.join(dirpaths, filename), 'a') as f:
                    f.write("newline")
            except:
                print "Directory empty or unable to open file."
            return x`

Comment: @Ruckol1 It's `os.path`, not `os.paths`. Please consider learning to read and understand the traceback messages printed in case of exceptions. They are quite informative.